# Golang update vendor dependencies every deploy

Tags: go, package-managers

I'm fairly new to Go coming from a Java background and am trying to figure out best practices for Go dependency management.

If I have Project A that has a dependency on Project B and I put a reference to Project B in my vendor package then running `go install` downloads everything I need. However, let's say I find a bug in Project B that I fix, how do I ensure that Project A stays up to date? As in, is there some way to do an install on every deploy to make sure that I'm not missing anything?

In Java, on every deploy I would do my own `mvn package` to best ensure that each deploy was self-sufficient. Is there some way to do the same in Go?

Apologies if this is a really basic question - but I couldn't find a good answer.

Comment: Are you using `dep` or `gomods` for dependency management?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

If you are using go 1.11 and above [go mod](https://blog.golang.org/using-go-modules) for prior versions
you can use [go dep](https://golang.github.io/dep/docs/introduction.html)